# Is it possible to have multiple blend modes on a single layer in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Lighten does a good job of removing a background from one of my images since it's transparent on a black background, but I want to apply another blend mode to make it match my overall image better. Can I apply two blend modes in any way?

Comment: Have you looked at the blending options? You can fake a lot of what the lighten (or darken) groups do  - with limitations, of course - using the "blend if" sliders.

Comment: Hi Michael, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: quick guess--would it work to put your layer in a layer folder, and give that layer folder a second blending mode?

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not possible to have more than one blending mode set per layer for existing pixels.

If you are painting, or drawing pixels onto a layer you can use the **tool** blending mode options before painting.

Comment: Also, similar to changing the tool blend mode, you can also duplicate layers and use different blend modes in them. If you want to avoid kind of destructive workflow, you could convert the layer to a Smart object before duplicating, and then apply the blend modes to the Smart objects. Depending on the situation, you can use Layer adjustments instead of Blend modes, to achieve similar results. The idea would be to have multiple Layer adjustments and one picture layer below them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Illustrator by creating a mask around the image and giving the layer a blend mode state while having the image with another blend mode. I have enjoyed working with multiply on the image and luminosity on the mask. I have not figured this out in Photoshop as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible when you create a adjust layer with no settings under the layer with the blend mode. Then set the layer with the blend mode to aclipped layer. Now you can use a second layer mode on the adjust layer.